# Popup browser compatibility

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, browser, webforms

I am using javascript to open popups in the browser, but the functionality and supported properties seems to vary.

In IE I can open a popup then resize it but if I open a popup from that one it won't resize.

In Chrome/Firefox, If I open a popup it comes up with a different size, then if I open a further popup from that window, it opens in a new tab alongside the parent window.

In Chrome I can't remove the address bar.

In Chrome/Firefox I can't prevent window resizing.

Is there a way to find out what is supported by each browser or get them all to behave the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out what is supported by each browser or get
>   them all to behave the same way?

No.

You have to bear in mind that user preferences can be set to override the default behavior, and some anti-virus suites include pop-up blocking add-ons.  In general, you also don't know if the client is viewing this on a mobile device (which likely can't even support pop-ups), or some really oddball browser.  (Linux users have options we'd never consider including text-only, etc.)  Dealing with the fact that you have limited control over the clients' configuration is just part of being a web developer.

My recommendation would be to rethink the design.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but consider things like [modal dialogs using JavaScript and css](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html) where appropriate, and just opening links with "target=_new" and letting the user's preference and browser dictate whether that's a pop-up or a new tab.

Comment: I will look into the target=_new and putting the user browser settings aside, how do developers get it to open and look the same across all of them?

Comment: We don't.  That's what I'm saying.  With web development the reality is that it won't look the same across all systems.  When designing for the web, you have to keep that in mind and do your best to just deal with it.  More here: http://www.noupe.com/design/websites-shouldnt-look-the-same-across-different-browsers%E2%80%A6here-is-why.html  And maybe some more helpful info here: http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery UI's dialog boxes. The framework will handle all browser differences internally.

Comment: You can only use a jquery dialog within the same window. It is useless if you need to keep additional windows open or open them from within each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening multiple dialogs from within dialogs in a web application, perhaps your UI should be rethought to fit web standards more closely. A dialog box in a browser is great for viewing or simple, 1-step actions, but beyond that they become more confusing and less useful.